# Connect to specific blockchain on CoinbaseWalletSdk provider init

Tags: web3js, coinbase-api, ethers.js, wallet-connect

I am trying to connect to the polygon chain when creating a new Web3Modal and the coinbaseWalletSdk.

According to what I found, the following code initializes the provider and should connect to chain id 137 (polygon). It does create the provider and connect to it, but the wallet app displays a message asking to switch to the Ethereum chain.

```
const providerOptions = {
    'custom-coinbase': {
        display: {
          name: 'Coinbase',
          description: 'Scan with Coinbase to connect',
          logo: "assets/coinbase_logo.jpg"
        },
        options: {
          appName: 'My app', // Your app name
          networkUrl: `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_KEY}`,
          chainId: 137,
        },
        package: CoinbaseWalletSDK,
        connector: async (_, options) => {
            const { appName, networkUrl, chainId } = options
            const coinbaseLink = new CoinbaseWalletSDK({
                appName
            });
            const provider = coinbaseLink.makeWeb3Provider(networkUrl, chainId);
            await provider.enable();
            return provider;
        }
    }
}
this.web3Modal = new Web3Modal.default({
    cacheProvider: false,
    providerOptions
});
let provider = await this.web3Modal.connectTo("custom-coinbase");
this.web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Okay, all goes well and after scanning the QR code presented it makes connection to my wallet.
But after allowing the connection in the wallet I get a popup that the website wants to switch to the ethereum network.

[image: Ethereum popup]

Only after switching chain ID manually, the wallet gets connected to the polygon chain.

```
const chainId = 137;
await this.web3.currentProvider.request({
    method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
    params: [{ chainId: Web3.utils.toHex(chainId) }],
});
```

[image: Switch polygon chain]

Is there a way to do it in one go? I would really like the user to be connected to the polygon chain immediately.

If this question is better asked on the ethereum.stackexchange then please feel free to move it there.

Answer (score 0):

There's one potential issue that I can see. You are using the wrong RPC for polygon:

```js
        options: {
          appName: 'My app', // Your app name
          networkUrl: `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_KEY}`,
          chainId: 137,
        },
```

Secondly, from the docs, it appears that your initialization should be:

```js
const providerOptions = {
  coinbasewallet: {
    package: CoinbaseWalletSDK,
    options: {
      appName: "My Awesome App",
      infuraId: "INFURA_ID",
      chainId: 137,
    }
  }
};
```

*Without* a custom connector.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. And the weird thing is. My app is unable to connect using normal coinbase providerOptions. Only a custom connection method allows the connection.

Comment: That is truly strange - I would recommend submitting a bug report.